# How to return list DTO contains a list of other DTO

Tags: java, spring-boot, dto

I'm new in dev web so if I make mistake, pardon me!. 
I have a Category DTO 1-n relate with Category Item DTO, two of them have  two field ID and Name.
If client call API to get all Category Item, I want to return list Category contain list of Category Item ralate by CategoryID. How can I excute that in DTO?

the JSON file return like:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/AeJmC.jpg

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add a List of CategoryItemDTO to your Category DTO , so your Category class should get like this:

```
class Category{
   Long uid;
   String name;
   List<CategoryItemDTO> categoryItems;
}
```